# Code Contracts and Programmatically compiling projects

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of legacy web projects that are compiled using a custom build application that we wrote. This because the depedencies were complex and the code... is... less than optimal. On the plus side it has recently been upgraded to .NET 4.5 and we are using Visual Studio 2013.

I recently started using code contracts in one of our other projects and really like the SoC it provides. I want to implement this in the legacy code that we are maintaining for new features (without doing a complete re-write). In development I have gotten it to work as long as I do a build from within VS and copy the compiled DLL files into the BIN folder of the web application (aps.net 32bit latest IIS).

I want to include the contracts in our release build as well using our Build tool. Otherwise I would have to use the tool and then use VS to create a release which is a 2 step process. I have complete source control over the tool (which is executed locally on my DEV PC) but I cannot get it to produce output with the code contracts. I read the Code Contract documentation and they mention the build script Microsoft.CodeContracts.targets and I have tried to add this into the build code without success. Admittedly my knowledge of the build process, build scripts, etc. is lacking at best. Any help / pointers in how to get this to work would be greatly appreciated. I would still like to normally compile my code in VS and have contracts work as well as use the build tool and and contracts work.

(i have not manually changed any of the CSPROJ files)

Build Code:
Build code is done using Microsoft.Build and Microsoft.Build.Framework assemblies.

```
var pc = new ProjectCollection();
var buildLogger = new FileLogger();

var logFilePath = @"MyLog.log";
buildLogger.Parameters = string.Format("logfile={0}", logFilePath);

var binDirectory = Path.Combine(outputWebDir, "Bin");
var globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
globalProperty.Add("OutputPath", binDirectory);
globalProperty.Add("Configuration", publishParams.ReleaseMode);
globalProperty.Add("Platform", publishParams.PlatformMode);
if (projectFileToPublish.IndexOf("SOTAQ.WebPoint.Web.csproj", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
    globalProperty.Add("SolutionDir", publishParams.SparcoSolutionPath);
if (isWebSite)
{
    globalProperty.Add("WebProjectOutputDir", outputWebDir);
    globalProperty.Add("DeployOnBuild", "True");
}
globalProperty.Add("CodeContractsInstallDir", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\");
globalProperty.Add("CodeContractRewriteCommand", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\Bin\ccrewrite.exe");
globalProperty.Add("CodeContractAnalysisTargets", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\MsBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.CodeContractAnalysis.targets");
globalProperty.Add("CodeContractsCCDocgenCommand", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\Bin\ccdocgen.exe");
globalProperty.Add("CodeContractsCCRefgenCommand", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\Bin\ccrefgen.exe");

string[] targets;
if (isWebSite)
    targets= new[] { "Build", "ResolveReferences", "_CopyWebApplication" };
else
    targets = new[] { "Build", "ResolveReferences" };


var buildRequestData = new BuildRequestData(projectFileToPublish, globalProperty, null, targets, null);
var buildParams = new BuildParameters(pc);
buildParams.Loggers = new[] {buildLogger};

BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParams, buildRequestData);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!
Thanks in advance,
-Igor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading and re-reading the diagnostic output from Visual Studio and comparing it to my build project and trying many various possible solutions I found online the answer was to add the variable CodeContractsEnableRuntimeChecking with value true.

```
globalProperty.Add("CodeContractsEnableRuntimeChecking", "true");
```

Once that was added everything worked as expected.

-Igor